# Images in grid - XSL-FO

Tags: xsl-fo

I try to implement a kind of grid system with images.
I would like to get something like this.[image] There will be more pages.
Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I managed with an inline element before the image. So first of all a block, after inline, and finally the image:

```
<fo:block margin-bottom="5mm" keep-with-next.within-page="always">
    <fo:inline></fo:inline>
    <fo:external-graphic src="image.jpg" content-width="90mm" content-height="scale-to-fit" />
</fo:block>
```

Comment: If you solved that issue, nice. I don't see how the above code you have formats the grid you specified unless its a two column document and the keeps are not needed. So you are formatting down the column and not across the page.

Comment: Yes, it's a two column document. Thanks, I'm gonna remove the keeps.

Comment: You do not need the keeps or the inline. What the inline probably did is break the keep in the FO engine possibly as it was an empty element and that can happen. All you need is to stack blocks like you are doing, whether they have text or images and left the FO engine format the pages in two columns.